# downloading and saving data underneath REDCap reports

Tags: r, api, for-loop

I'm trying to use a for loop to get R to loop through a table of inputs with multiple columns, with each column corresponding to a specific variable.

The error message is

```
For Loop and API QuestionError in 
read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,
 : no lines available in input
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the script that I wrote:

```
##Call server
library(RCurl)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(redcapAPI)

TableForR<-read.csv("//usershare/users$/aweible1/Profile_Data/Desktop/REDCap Monthly Check/TableForR.csv")


for(j in seq_len(nrow(TableForR))){
    labelFile <- RCurl::postForm(
    uri = "https://redcap.uhhospitals.org/redcap/api/",
    token = TableForR[j,1],
    content = 'report',
    report_id = TableForR[j,2],
    format = 'csv',
    type = 'flat',
    rawOrLabel = 'label',
    exportDataAccessGroups = 'true',
    .opts = curlOptions(ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
    )
        backup <- read.csv(text = labelFile, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
            write.csv(backup, file = TableForR[j,3], row.names=FALSE)
}
```

I was expecting it to spit out 273 files in a folder on my desktop based on the variable inputs in a csv file. This would help me tremendously because I'm trying to automate an API.

Answer (score 0):

Consider letting [`REDCapR::redcap_report()`](https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/reference/redcap_report.html) talk to the server, and writing a loop around it.

```r
uri          <- "https://bbmc.ouhsc.edu/redcap/api/"

ds_control <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~token,                              ~report_id,  ~file_name,
    "9A81268476645C4E5F03428B8AC3AA7B",       5980L,      "a.csv",
    "9A81268476645C4E5F03428B8AC3AA7B",       6431L,      "b.csv"
  )


download_and_save_report <- function(token, report_id, file_name) {
  message("Processing report ", ds_control$report_id[i])

  d <-
    REDCapR::redcap_report(
      redcap_uri = uri,
      token      = token,
      report_id  = report_id
    )$data
  
  readr::write_csv(d, file_name)
}

for(i in seq_len(nrow(ds_control))) {
  download_and_save_report(
    token       = ds_control$token[i], 
    report_id   = ds_control$report_id[i], 
    file_name   = ds_control$file_name[i]
  )
}
```

output for console & file system

```
Downloading report 5980
5 records and 5 columns were read from REDCap in 0.1 seconds.  The http status code was 200.
Downloading report 6431                            
5 records and 2 columns were read from REDCap in 0.1 seconds.  The http status code was 200.
```

[image: csvs]

This call to `purrr::walk()` accomplishes the same thing as the for loop.

```r
ds_control |> 
  purrr::pwalk(
    \(token, report_id, file_name) {
      download_and_save_report(token, report_id, file_name)      
    }
  )
```

(Note to new users, this token points to an example project without PHI.  Please don't post tokens to real projects with sensitive data.)